# Create a collection type that once will be a List<T> and in other uses will be Stack<t>

Tags: c#, design-patterns, c#-3.0

I am developing a card game.
I created a card collection that I use for two cases :

1. A specific player cards.
2. First package.

For the first use I need that the collection type will be List.
For the second use I need that the collection type will be Stack.

Is it possible to create a collection type that once will be a List and in 
different use it will be a Stack?

Both card collcetions use have the same functions, that's why I need this capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inherit from `List<T>` and add the `Push` and `Pop` methods and you're pretty much there.

If you actually want to prevent List functionality (random access, etc) when it's in "stack mode" then you'll want to create an `IStack<T>` interface and use it as an `IStack<T>` when you only want stack functionality.